# New activity on resolved case (CRM 2011 online)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

We have a strange situation and I'm at a loss how to investigate. If user1/securityRole1 gets a resolved case shared (read + share) with them, when they open the case it shows up as readonly (good) but the activity ribbon button is active. This means they can create a new activity regarding the resolved case (by clicking the button which auto populates the regarding field to the read only resolved case).

Meanwhile, the case owner/securityRole2 sees the button greyed out when viewing the case but can create a new activity by File/New/Activity and selecting the case as regarding manually.

User3/admin security role sees the same as the case owner.

If I add admin role to user1 the button gets greyed out and if I take admin role away again, it becomes enabled.

How can this be? Surely user1 cannot gain a right by having a role removed?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No matter whether Activity ribbon is greyed out or not user can still go to Home > Activities > New and set the resolved case into Regarding of the new activity form.

You might consider adding some javascript / precreate plugin on Create of Activity so that you can throw appropriate error message to the user and prevent the above from happening altogether.